# How do I go about asking a question regarding what makes a story possible?

Tags: discussion, tags, asking-questions, terminology

I'm thinking in particular about the Adjustment Bureau movie, and its base, the short story Adjustment Team, by Philip K. Dick. I would like to ask about the [this question] of these stories that allows adjustments to be made to our world, e.g. "Do these stories use a glossed over technology based [this question] or a more magical or fantasy based [this question]?"

I'm not talking about the plots though.

Comment: So you want to ask if a fictional thing would be real-world possible?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your question might get closed as not constructive or not a real question. Since the technology doesn't exist, the question would surely be answered with, "It's a fictional device".